# Remove all inline JavaScript - Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

In my code I have a parent DOM element `docElem`. This is an iframe containing a complete HTML document. Now I want to remove **all** inline JavaScript. How to do that in JQuery. Do we have any selector that can pull out all elements that have an attribute that matches `on.*` regex?

Please Note that I am asking about all inline script not `onclick` alone....

**EDIT**
To eliminate any confusion here is a example code:

```
var docHtml = '<html><head></head><body ><img src="smiley.gif" ><img src="smiley2.gif" onfocus="methodCall()"><div  onclick="methodCall()" id="uvTab" ></div></body></html>';
var docElem = $($.parseHTML('<iframe></iframe>'))
     .append($.parseHTML(docHtml, true));
var tagList = //some thing here that can bring me the img tag and the div tag.
```

Comment: what you have tried ?

Comment: no simple regex approach like you hoped for.

Comment: @Tariq do you want to change in Iframe ? If yes then it is not possible.

Comment: your parent DOM node is an iframe? do you mean that you entire "code" is in html document that is loaded in an iframe of another page? or is it the other way around and your document is embedding another document in an iframe - and you want to remove those attributes from the code loaded in an iframe?

Comment: `querySelectAll(*)` to loop through all elements. For each element loop through the attributes looking for inline JS. Also check for `script` elements. Remove these. PROFIT!

Comment: Loop over all _Nodes_, loop over all _attributes_, if _attribute_ begins _on*_, (check against whitelist then) remove the attribute. This may not prevent some from firing, e.g. _onload, onerror_.

Comment: @PeeHaa you can't remove `<script>` before it's executed. Why `querySelectorAll` and not `getElementsByTagName` or even `document.all`?

Comment: Added and example code.

Comment: Please vote to reopen this question. The poster has added source code and it's now clear enough to answer. In fact I have an answer ready with a working demo code but I can't post it as long as this question is "on hold"

Comment: @rsp please post your answer. It seems they have re-opened it.

Comment: @Tariq I've already posted my answer [**HERE**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23952684/remove-all-inline-javascript-jquery/23963908#23963908). Someone has voted it down for some reason but you should still see it below.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [html-sanitizer](https://code.google.com/p/google-caja/wiki/JsHtmlSanitizer)
from the [Google Caja](https://code.google.com/p/google-caja/) project. It can be used stand-alone in the browser.

You can get it from:

```
http://caja.appspot.com/html-css-sanitizer-minified.js
```

or:

```
http://caja.appspot.com/html-sanitizer-minified.js
```

(depending on whether or not you need to sanitize css as well)

You have to define two functions to tell the sanitizer how you want it to treat URLs and elements IDs (I'll name them `sanUrl()` and `sanId()` here).

For example you may want to completely remove IDs so that they don't interfere with your own IDs:

```
function sanId(id) {
  return undefined;
}
```

or you may want to add some prefix:

```
function sanId(id) {
  return "PREFIX" + id;
}
```

or just use them unchanged if it's ok for you:

```
function sanId(id) {
  return id;
}
```

The same with URLs:

```
function sanUrl(url) {
  // sanitize urls if needed
  // eg. add a prefix or remove relative/absolute urls etc.
  return url;
}
```

Now you can use the `html_sanitize()` function like this:

```
var sanitizedHtml = html_sanitize(originalHtml, sanUrl, sanId);
```

It will strip much more than what you described which means that you won't get into trouble if you have some input that you haven't anticipated.

It will also strip the html, head and body tags so if you need them you can add:

```
fullHtml = "<html><head></head><body>" + sanitizedHtml + "</body></html>";
```

You can also eg. get the image URLs using a code like this:

```
$(sanitizedHtml).find('img').addBack().filter('img')
  .each(function (i, el) {
    var url = $(el).attr('src');
    // do something with the URL:
    alert(url);
  });
```

See this demo:

http://codepen.io/rsp/pen/hLmcE

Comment: Thanks. I was looking for something like this. No idea why this answer had a down vote on it.