# NodeJS: Safety-Check if uploaded file contains HTML

Tags: html, node.js, file, validation

My NodeJS/Express service processes uploaded HTML files. For safety reasons, I'd like to check whether the file actually is an valid HTML file.

I would accept any answers that would recommend me useful libraries/source code snippets for doing so.

Thank you!

Comment: Have a  look https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-validator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following projects can help you with that:

- https://github.com/validator/validator
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/valimate
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-validator
- https://github.com/mozilla/html5-lint

Bot for safety reasons it's not enough to make sure that it's valid HTML. I would actually make sure that it doesn't contain JavaScript, or at least some insecure constructs in JavaScript. For that you may use:

- https://code.google.com/p/google-caja/wiki/JsHtmlSanitizer

or something like that. See this answer for more details:

- [Remove all inline JavaScript - Jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23952684/remove-all-inline-javascript-jquery/23963908#23963908)

The question was about jQuery but the problem is more general so it may give you some info.