# How to disable inline javascript in html?

Tags: javascript

I have html entered by user that is put in an iframe. The purpose is to suppress all inline javascript in the html. Have thought about Regexp to remove all scripts, but it caught only `<script> ... </script>`, but no `<txt onload='..javascript...`

This is the regex: `/<\s*script[^>]*>[^<]*<\s*\/\s*script\s*>/gi`

How can I block all js in the entered html?

Comment: The functionality you are looking for is called `sanitizing`. Check this question and answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23952684/remove-all-inline-javascript-jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set `sandbox=""` in the iframe tag and that won't allow scripts to execute.

To figure it out you can add the `sandbox` attribute in this demo https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_iframe, then run it and open your console.

Chrome displays this message:

> Blocked script execution in '' because the document's frame is
>   sandboxed and the 'allow-scripts' permission is not set.